# Ruby string interpolation equivalent to python's .format()

Tags: ruby, string, string-interpolation, language-comparisons

In python I can do

```
_str = "My name is {}"
...
_str = _str.format("Name")
```

In ruby when I try

```
_str = "My name is #{name}"
```

The interpreter complains that the variable **name** is undefined, so it's expecting

```
_str = "My name is #{name}" => {name =: "Name"}
```

How can I have a string placeholder in ruby for later use?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use Delayed Interpolation.

```
str = "My name is %{name}"
# => "My name is %{name}"

puts str % {name: "Sam"}
# => "My name is Sam"
```

The %{} and % operators in Ruby allows delaying the string interpolation until later. The %{} defines named placeholders in the string and % binds a given input into the placeholders.

Answer (score 0):

The interpreter is not expecting a hash, it's expecting a variable named `name`.

```
name = "Sam"
p str = "My name is #{name}" # => "My name is Sam"
```

The %  method can be used as @rastasheep demonstrates. It can be used in a simpler way:

```
str = "My name is %s"
p str % "Name" # => "My name is Name"
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the previous answers, you can use %s in place of {} for simplicity and flexibility.  Use array instead of string if you have multiple unnamed place holders.

```
_str = "%s is a %s %s"
...
_str % %w(That nice movie)  # => "That is a nice movie"
```